# read serialized data using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have a array of C struct, and I'm serializing it to a file, and I need to retrive that data to memory again.

```
movie list[50]; //array

typedef struct{
    int code;
    int year;
    float price;
    char title[50];
    char director[30];
    char description[255];
} movie;
```

serialized data exemple

```
1|1990|9.900000|Hello world|Foo bar baz|lorem ipsum bla bla|
34|1994|4.900000|lorem ipsum|lorem ipsum|lorem ipsum|
23|1993|5.100000|lorem ipsum|lorem ipsum|lorem ipsum|
.
.
.
```

To serialize I just traverse the array and fprintf every property to a line.

But to read the data the obvious doesn't work

```
while( fscanf("%d|%d|%f|%s|%s|%s|",&list[i].code, &list[i].year, ...)!= EOF){
i++;
...
}
```

Comment: Are you able to start small? Like read just the first digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does NOT work

```
sscanf(input,"%[ˆ|]|%[ˆ|]|%[ˆ|]",string1,string2,string3);
```

The mistake was so subtle that I took almost 3 hours to find the answer to my problem:

```
sscanf(input,"%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]",string1,string2,string3);
```

The problem is probably because I'm using `U.S International English` layout keyboard on my U.S. macbook.

This cause the `^` key (Shift-6) to appear as a accent `ˆ` until you press a consonant it turns to `â ê î ô û` or if you press spacebar it turn the accent to a character, and I never realized that these two `ˆ^` was different.

I'm not sure about english, but at least in portuguese the ^ ins not a character is called a circumflex accent, is used on consonants â ê î ô û to represent different pronunciation.

So if you're using a American keyboard you will have to press Shift+6 and then Spacebar to make a `^`

Comment: Yikes... "subtle" indeed!  Who'd want to be a programmer? :-]

Comment: lol maybe I should have listened to one that told me that I should have taken medicine course.

Comment: I believe you can accept your own answer to help indicate that post is well answered.

Answer (score 1):

"the obvious doesn't work"... that's when you read the function's manpage :-(.

The `%s` format doesn't stop reading a string when it hits a `|`... if you look at the fscanf documentation you'll see there's another format instruction allowing you to control which characters are read into the string vs. terminating the conversion....